# Histogram of events with different durations (Given their start and end times)

Tags: python, performance, numpy, histogram

I have a Numpy array `A` of shape `nX2`, representing `n` different events. The first column holds the starting times of the events, and the second holds the respective durations of each event.

For some time duration `[0, T]` and `N` different equidistant time points, I would like a count of how many events are ongoing at each time point. (i.e. an integer array of length `N`, each entry has the number of events that started before that time and lasted till after)

What is the most efficient way to achieve this in Python?

*I know what I'm asking for isn't really a histogram. If someone has a better term feel free to edit the title

Comment: Could you give some sample data and expected output? I'm not exactly clear on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. The idea is: for each bin, determine which events have started before the end of the bin but end after the start of the bin.

```
A = np.array([[1, 5, 6, 10], [5, 4, 1, 1]]).T

start = A[:, 0]
end = A.sum(axis=1)

lower = 0
upper = 100
N = 10    
bins = np.linspace(lower, upper, num=N+1)
[( (end > bins[n]) & (start < bins[n+1]) ).sum() for n in range(N)]
```